# django mysql gives page not found (404) while sqlite works fine

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite

I have two settings files for my django project with different database settings.

First:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbname',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'megahardbreakingpassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB',
        }
    }
}
```

And second:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
        'NAME': 'db.sqlite3',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

When I run server with second database settings project works fine, but when I run first settings file with mysql, django returns 404 error for all urls.

I also use django-hosts for implementing subdomains patterns, so maybe something wrong here. My hosts.py code:

```
from django_hosts import patterns, host


host_patterns = patterns('',
    host(r'^$', 'project.urls', name='host'),
)
```

I use django 1.4.2 and Python 2.7.9

Comment: DB settings can hardly be the reason... Are you sure there are no more differences between two settings files?

Comment: Absolutely. I copied one file and then change DATABASES options

Comment: databases do not produce 404 errors. You are having a view that queries the database and raises a 404 when it encounters an error.  Please look at the log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And finally I found answer! According to [e4c5's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552523/django-mysql-gives-page-not-found-404-while-sqlite-works-fine/32561376#comment52970967_32552523) I searched problem in my views instead of my settings files. I wrote simple unittest and it gives me some strange tracebeck about my MySQL database such as wrong column name and deprecation warnings about duplication indexes.

I reinstall older version of MySQL server (5.0.70 instead of 5.6.25), run syncdb and migrations again and it completely solved my problems. So God bless TDD!